# Run script on next reboot and remove script

Tags: scripts, systemd

As part of a flow that installs Ubuntu 16.04 (from scratch to fully configured, with a lot of extra software installed and changes made post installation), I need a way to run scripts (that are downloaded during installation) after the next reboot (and only the next reboot) and remove the scripts, and end with another reboot.

I already have a service that I use for running scripts after the first boot, but without deleting them (this can be triggered again at a later time if needed), but I now find that I need run scripts that must be deleted afterwards, as they contain sensitive information.

The systemd service I am using for the other scripts look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=First run specifics
After=network-online.target
Requires=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/firstrun
ExecStart=/root/bin/firstrun-wrapper "${PASSWORD}"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/default/firstrun and /root/bin/firstrun-wrapper are added during installation. /etc/default/firstrun contains a password and is deleted by the firstrun-wrapper script, preventing the service from starting again after a reboot.
firstrun-wrapper executes a bunch of scripts all added during installation and finishes with a reboot.

The service can be used again later to run the same setup (by adding the /etc/default/firstrun file)

So my question is. **How can I run a script after the next reboot, removing the script after it has executed, and after removing the script, trigger a reboot?**

It doesn't matter to me whether this uses systemd or not, and I am fine with an 'empty' (empty meaning containing no relevant/sensitive information) file being left on the system after this.

My initial thought was to modify my current service. I thought I could add another script in firstrun-wrapper that removes certain files and modifies firstrun-wrapper not to include them anymore, and execute that script through ExecStopPost, but that isn't triggered by the service finishing on its own (from what I can tell). Even if I can modify the firstrun-wrapper file while it is being executed, I understand that would be bad practice, so I am trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `crontab -e` for the user who will run the script - `sudo crontab -e` for **root** or `sudo -u user_name -e` to edit crontab for **user_name**. Insert `@reboot /path/to/file` (NB! Don't forget the empty new line).
The script itself should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
do_your_stuff
# remove from root specific crontab setting all the information about the script
sed -i '/@reboot \/path\/to\/file/d' /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
# remove the script file itself
rm -- "$0"
# reboot the machine in 2 minutes
shutdown -r +2
```

To automate this process you can use Ansible. Here is an example of a simple playbook, I ran it on my localhost:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: cron job
    cron:
      name: "a job for reboot"
      special_time: reboot
      job: "/path/to/file"
```

First, you need to run the playbook, it updates the cron tasks for `root`. After reboot the script should be deleted just like the `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` file entry with **@reboot** string. You are free to modify the file to totally delete crontab for root is necessary.

Comment: Does deleting the script file itself not cause any issue whatsoever? And what will happen if the cron entry stays but the file is not there?

Comment: I tested more simple version of the script, it works fine. If you use `/etc/crontab` for autostart of the script, you should add a line `sed -i /@reboot/d /etc/crontab` to remove the entry. Updated my answer.

Comment: I want to try this out, but just to be sure I understand it correctly. I add @reboot /path/to/file to the crontab, and the sed line in the script removes that line again when running the script?

Comment: I've added @reboot /testscript (and placed a script at /testscript) to /etc/crontab but it doesn't seem to trigger on reboot. If this is supposed to work with 16.04, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, `sed` removes the line from crontab file before telling the machine to reboot. Is your script executable?

Comment: The script I am testing with is executable and looks like this: 
#!/bin/bash (newline)
/usr/bin/touch /reboottest There is a comment at the top of /etc/crontab that says The file has username fields that none of the other crontabs do, I'm guessing it could have something to do with that? Should the line be @reboot root /testscript ?

Comment: Updated my answer. You are correct, it doesn't work for `/etc/crontab`, my bad.

Comment: I have accepted the answer as it does answer my question. However I did not phrase my question properly. I need to use this as part of a fully automated installation process. Is there anyway to make this non interactive? I tried simply writing to /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root, but it doesn't seem to work before I've typed crontab -e and saved through there.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to expand your answer with a way to automate it using Ansible. After some digging I chose to go with a (in my eyes) simpler option though. I simply append @reboot /path/to/my/script into /var/spools/cron/crontabs/root and then crontab /var/spools/cron/crontabs/root - this requires no interaction and was simple to add to my installation process.